# SUMPRODUCT - return a row number

Tags: excel

I am trying to return the row number in which a sheet Column matches a value AND another column in that same sheet matches a value AND yet another column in that same4 sheet matches a value.

Here is some code:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!C:C=Total!$A5)*(Data!A:A=Total!E35)*(Data!B:B=Total!F35)*(ROW(Data!C:C)-1))
```

Where Data!C:C is a column of dates and Total!$A5 is a cell with the same format type date
And Data!A:A is a column of unique text values and Total!E35 is a cell with a text value
AND Data!B:B is a column of unique text values and Total!E35 is a cell with a text value

There is only one match for the given combination I described.

I am stuck on the latter part of the formula, I believe. Where I multiply the ROW(Data! blah blah blah...

Can somebody help?!

Comment: Since you're using entire columns, you don't need the "-1".

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. It works for me as posted. Are you getting an error? An incorrect value?

Comment: @DickKusleika I'm getting the value of 0 - so I suppose it's an error (row 0?) - this one is killing me!

Comment: A zero means it didn't find a match. Or, since you're subtracting one, it found a match in row one.

Comment: Check for leading or trailing spaces or other unprintable characters. That can cause a mismatch when the cells look the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a row number `MATCH` might be better, i.e. this "array formula"

`=MATCH(1,(Data!C:C=Total!$A5)*(Data!A:A=Total!E35)*(Data!B:B=Total!F35),0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Getting an `#NA` @Barry ... any insight as to why... I'm sure the combinations should return a row number.

Comment: Check your data. You've now got two formulas telling you there's no match.

Comment: Sometimes dates come in as *Datetimes* but are formatted to only show the date. If you are comparing datetimes to a date, then you will almost never get a match. Split out the dates and times into separate columns or use `INT()` to truncate the time out of the datetime.